# Binding not updating from INotifyPropertyChanged class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am new to WPF. I have binded the source class properties to target controls successfully. But whenever the properties value changes the UI controls not reflecting the updated data. Please help

WPF Code:

```
<Label Name="Panel_ch1Mode" Content="{Binding Path=Mode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  FontFamily="Roboto Regular" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
```

My Class:

```
public class ClassName: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
//Auto Refresh
        private string mode;
        public string Mode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mode;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mode = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Mode");
            }
        }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));


        }
}
```

Comment: How do you know you have bound successfully?

Comment: have you set DataContext?

Comment: I would check an output window and look for error 40:, maybe your datacontext was not created? or its in a wrong scope?

Comment: I have set DataContext as below

Comment: ClassName ObjClassName= new ClassName();

public MeasurementDisplayScreen()
{
            
            InitializeComponent();
            Channel1DockPannel.DataContext = ObjClassName;
            
}

Comment: When you update the `Mode` property, make sure you do it on the same ClassName instance as the one you're using as DataContext. So call e.g. `ObjClassName.Mode = "A new mode";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Just remove from xaml the  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay. )

Improve your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged linke this:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: While this is valid (because `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=TwoWay` don't have an effect here) and `CallerMemberName` may be considered as an improvement, it does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

In code behind please check if the ViewModel is "wired" to the View:

```
   public YourView()
   {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ClassName();
   }
```

You have to keep in mind that a binding is always related to DataContext.

Comment: Nice downvote, I don't understand why, because it might be a solution for others, but...ok...